# plot a surface using a nonrectangular domain

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-3dplot

There is a way to plot a surface in a nonrectangular domain?
For example, plot f(x,y)=x^2+y^2 where 0 <= x <= 1$ and x^2 <= y <= x?
I have the following code, almost the result witha conditional structure.

```
\documentclass[11pt,border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=0:1, y domain=0:1,samples=20,no marks]
\addplot3[surf,gray,samples=30, samples y=30](x,y,0);
\addplot3[surf,colormap/hot,samples=30, samples y=30](x,y,{(x < y && x> y^2?x^2+y^2:0)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The output is:
[image]

I would like, to disconsider the 0 value (out of my domain). In Gnuplot, it accept `NaN` if the point are out of the domain; but here no.

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution is to parametrize the domain, changing the variables so that the new domain is "rectangular". For instance, if we take `y=x*t+x^2*(1-t)` as in the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage   {pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset  {compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
  xlabel=$x$,
  ylabel=$y$,
  zmin=0,
  zmax=2,
  domain=0:1, y domain=0:1,
  samples=20, samples y=10,
  variable y=t,
  view={30}{45}
]
\addplot3[mesh,gray]               (x, {x*t+x^2*(1-t)}, 0);
\addplot3[surf, colormap name=hot] (x, {x*t+x^2*(1-t)}, {x^2+(x*t+x^2*(1-t))^2});  
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

we can obtain this picture:
[image]